# Field in Access VBA code showing as Empty

Tags: vba, ms-access, field, is-empty

I'm being tasked with altering a field "TimeAfterClass" (double) to produce a new field "NewTimeAfterClass" (also double) which would contain unique numbers.  I created a button to accomplish this and it doesn't produce any errors but it also doesn't update the NewTimeAfterClass field and when I hover over [TimeAfterClass] it shows as Empty.  Any suggestions as to why this is happening?  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim CurrentTimeAfterClass As Double
Dim NewTimeAfterClass As Double
Dim strSQL As String
Dim increment As Double
increment = 0.01
'Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

'Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .Open "Scores", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    .MoveFirst
    While Not .EOF
    CurrentTimeAfterClass = [TimeAfterClass]
    CurrentIncrement = 0
    CurrentIncrement = increment
        NewTimeAfterClass = CurrentTimeAfterClass + CurrentIncrement
            If CurrentIncrement > 0 Then
            CurrentIncrement = CurrentIncrement * (-1)
            Else
            CurrentIncrement = CurrentIncrement * (-1) + increment
            End If
    .Update
    .MoveNext
    Wend
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to prefix with rs, so `rs![TimeAfterClass]`

Comment: You're not assigning any value to increment. You're not updating the New field at all - you're upating the double variable - and like @Pam Leonard says you need to preface your fields with a "!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with increment, so I can only assume you know what you're doing.

To make the Update work try this - maybe on a backup db??

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim CurrentTimeAfterClass As Double

    ' You don't need this if you're updating the field directly
    'Dim NewTimeAfterClass As Double

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim increment As Double
    increment = 0.01

    'Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    'Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .Open "Scores", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
        CurrentTimeAfterClass = !TimeAfterClass
        CurrentIncrement = 0
        CurrentIncrement = increment

        !NewTimeAfterClass = CurrentTimeAfterClass + CurrentIncrement
        If CurrentIncrement > 0 Then
            CurrentIncrement = CurrentIncrement * (-1)
        Else
            CurrentIncrement = CurrentIncrement * (-1) + increment
        End If

        .Update
        .MoveNext
        Wend
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion.  I tried it and now I get the run-time error "Number of rows with pending changes exceeded the limit".  My whole table only has 22 rows so I'm sure it is something goofy.

Comment: The .MoveNext seemed to be causing an issue, so I tried commenting it out and tried again...now it is stuck in "not responding"...at least it's different.  I'm still plugging away.

Comment: Ok, I commented out the .MoveFirst and the .MoveNext and that seemed to resolve the issue.  Thank you again for your help and now I can move forward.